# POST request for Office365 using REST API

Tags: office-365, rest

I want to POST method request for Office365 using REST API. For example, Feed/Post, Post/Reply, and Post/Like.

Request Header:

> Accept : application/json; odata=verbose
>
> Content-Type: application/json; odata=verbose
>
> Method: POST
>
> ContentLength: *content.Length*
>
> CookieContainer: *cookieContainer*

Request content about Feed/Post

```
"restCreationData":
 {
  "__metadata":{
        "type":"SP.Social.SocialRestPostCreationData"
      },
  "ID":null,
  "creationData":{
        "__metadata":{
          "type":"SP.Social.SocialPostCreationData"
        },
        "ContentText":"This post was published using REST.", 
        "UpdateStatusText":false
  }
}
```

But I get 403 status error.

**Can anyone tell me How to post method request for Office365.**

Comment: Are you doing this operation from a SharePoint App? If yes, you will have to give your App the Permissions to access the Social Feed. You can do that from the AppManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://<site url>/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'Title': 'New title' }),
        headers: { 
            "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-length": <length of post body>,
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "IF-MATCH": "*"
        },
        success: doSuccess,
        error: doError
});
```

Reference: [Writing data by using the REST interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164022(v=office.15).aspx#WritingData)